# How to mount mosquitto docker logs to local pc

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, mosquitto

I have installed `eclipse-mosquitto` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-mosquitto) in Ubuntu. I am trying to run it using `docker-compose`. Mosquitto needs 3 directories as explained in docker hub page:

1. config : which contains mosquitto.conf and bridge.conf files
2. data: which contains mosquitto.db file
3. log: which contains mosquitto.log file

In my local PC I have created a directory named `mosquitto` which has all the above directory and files:

```
mosquitto

    -> config
        -> mosquitto.conf
        -> conf.d
            -> bridge.conf 
    -> data
        -> mosquitto.db
    -> log
        -> mosquitto.log
```

Below is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
    mosquitto:
        image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/john/Documents/docker/mosquitto:/mosquitto
        restart: always
```

and I am starting it as `sudo docker-compose up`. Its container starts to run fine and I can see all the directories and files properly mounted inside the mosquitto container. I can see the logs starts to come and `mosquitto.log` file size is also increasing inside the container but there is no log present in my local pc.

Why is this happening when I have mounted the volume. I want to also get the logs in the `mosquitto.log` in ubuntu local pc. How can I do this. Can anyone please suggest some good solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is because docker is creating 2 local volumes and mounting them on top of the `/mosquitto` directory to hold the persistence and log data.

Add the extra mounts to the volumes section and it will then bind the local directories rather than create unnamed local volumes.

```
version: '2.4'

services:
    mosquitto:
        image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
        volumes:
            - /home/john/Documents/docker/mosquitto:/mosquitto
            - /home/john/Documents/docker/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
            - /home/john/Documents/docker/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
        restart: always
```